# DropDownListFor ... selected value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my model, I have a list of country : `Model.ListCountry`. The Country class has some fields :
Id, Code, ValueFR, ValueUS

In my model, I have a Customer and this customer has a country : `Model.Customer.Country`

I tried this :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Record.Customer.Country, new SelectList(Model.ListCountry, "Code", "FR"), new { id = "lbCountry" })
```

No idea ?

Thanks,

Update1:
In the database, I save the Id, but in the dropdown as "option value" I use the code, and as display fiels ValueFR or ValueUS depending of the language user

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to preselect a value in a dropdown list set the corresponding property to this value in your controller action:

```
model.Record.Customer.Country = "FR";
```

As far as the dropdown list generation is concerned the two string arguments you are passing to the [SelectList constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505286.aspx) represent the property names of the model corresponding respectively to the Value and Text. So I guess it should be more like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.Record.Customer.Country, 
    new SelectList(Model.ListCountry, "Code", "ValueFR"), 
    new { id = "lbCountry" }
)
```

In this example we are using the `Code` property as Values in the dropdown list and `ValueFR` property as Text. So in this case you must ensure that you are setting the `model.Record.Customer.Country` property to some `Code` that exists in the list and the dropdown will automatically preselect this item.

Another possibility use the following [SelectList constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553.aspx) which allows you to specify a selected value as 4<sup>th</sup> parameter:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.Record.Customer.Country, 
    new SelectList(Model.ListCountry, "Code", "ValueFR", "FR"), 
    new { id = "lbCountry" }
)
```

Comment: @Kris-I, if use `Id` as `option value` and want to preselect an item use the `CountryId` as first argument of the DropDownListFor helper and in your controller action set the value of this property to the corresponding country id you want to preselect. Also note that having two properties `ValueFR` and `ValueUS` to handle localization is a bad practice. You should have only one property and based on the current language setting your repository would populate the property with the correct value. What if tomorrow you needed to handle a third language? Would you modify all your code?

Comment: I know about the bad practice, it's just temp. Anyway .... the dropdown list value is still not selected.

Comment: @Kris-I, it's simple: the first argument you are passing to the DropDownListFor helper **must** have a value that is contained in the value property of the collection you are passing as second argument. If you respect this rule the corresponding item will be preselected. If you don't, and the Id is not present in the collection, either the default value will be selected or the first one.

Comment: Damn, I wish I could vote this answer up 10 times... spent ages trying to get it to pre-select a value in the dropdown using the selectedValue parameter of the SelectList constructor, when all I needed to do is set the model property that is associated with the drop-down.