# Editing form with dropdownlist, showing value in dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, drop-down-menu

I have editing form with dropdownlist. It's work properly but when I'm on a editin page, in dropdownlist I see first value from a list. I want make, I can see value which I have in database. ex. I have company: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and when I editing I have default company 1. But in databese for this product is company 4. Do if I will editin form in dropdownlist I would like have defoult showing company 4 instead 1. 
I hope you understand what I have on the mind.

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult edytuj_prod(int ID_Produkt)
        {
            var prod = (from d in baza.Produkts
                        join s in baza.Firmas on d.ID_firma equals s.ID_firma where ID_Produkt == d.ID_Produkt
                        select new { d.ID_firma, d.nazwa_prod, d.ilosc, d.jednostka, d.cena, d.ID_Produkt, s.nazwa }).First();

            var firma = baza.Firmas;
            produktModel pr = new produktModel()
            {
                firmaList = firma.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = x.ID_firma.ToString(),
                    Text = x.nazwa
                })
            };


            pr.nazwa_prod = prod.nazwa_prod;
            pr.ilosc = prod.ilosc;
            pr.jednostka = prod.jednostka;
            pr.cena = prod.cena;

            return View(pr);
```

View:

```
<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ID_firma, Model.firmaList)


        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want the dropdown list to have the saved item selected instead of having the first item on the list. If so, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5371684/390564)

Also you could check [these constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.aspx):

```
public SelectList(IEnumerable items, Object selectedValue)
public SelectList(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, Object selectedValue)
```