# Retrieving value posted in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a dropdownlist containining

```
{
   Select a title,
   Mr,
   Ms,
   Mrs
}
```

that was initialized like this

```
//in model file
Mymodel mm=new Mymodel();
mm.Titles=new []
{
   new SelectListItem{....}
}

.....
//in view file and was set up inside a form

@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Title, Model.Titles,"Select a title");
```

After I click the submit button I would like to get the slected value in the dropdown list.

Comment: You can refer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371665/dropdownlistfor-selected-value

Answer (score 2):

You could have your `[HttpPost]` controller action to which the form is submitted take the same view model as parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(Mymodel model)
{
    // the model.Title property will contain the selected value here
}
```

Also the `Titles` collection will not be sent to your HttpPost action. That's how HTML works. Only the selected value of a `<select>` element is sent when a form is submitted. For this reason you need to repopulate the `Titles` property if you intend to redisplay the same view.

For example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(Mymodel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // there was a validation error, for example the user didn't select any title
        // and the Title property was decorated with the [Required] attribute =>
        // repopulate the Titles property and show the view
        model.Titles = .... same thing you did in your GET action
        return View(model);
    }

    // at this stage the model is valid => you could use the model.Title
    // property to do some processing and redirect
    return RedirectToAction("Success");
}
```